# Expected class-name before { token - very simple

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've seen many answers for this question, know what to look for and still can see that. Looks like some obvious problem.

Algorithm.h:

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class Algorithm
{
private:
    T data;
    T result;
public:
    Algorithm(T in){
        data = in;
    }

    void compute();

    void displayData(){
        cout<<data<<endl;
    }

    T getResult(){
        return result;
    }
};

#endif // ALGORITHM_H
```

Bubble.h:

```
#ifndef BUBBLE_H
#define BUBBLE_H

#include "algorithm.h"

class Bubble : public Algorithm{
public:
    Bubble();
};

#endif // BUBBLE_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "bubble.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Algorithm<int> a(1);
    Algorithm<char> b('a');

    a.displayData();
    b.displayData();


    return 0;
}
```

Error is:

> /home/user/Projects/Algorithms/main.cpp:1: In file included from
>   ../Algorithms/main.cpp:1:0: /home/user/Projects/Algorithms/bubble.h:6:
>   error: expected class-name before '{' token  class Bubble : public
>   Algorithm{
>                                   ^

Why compiler cannot see Algorithm class? I included it in Bubble.h, so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to provide the template argument for `Algorithm`. If you fix this, your code compiles fine. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5871b6f5ed7747d6))

Answer (score 1):

Bubble inherits from the Algorithm class, which is a template. So it also needs the template specification:

```
#ifndef BUBBLE_H
#define BUBBLE_H

#include "algorithm.h"

template <typename T>
class Bubble : public Algorithm<T> {
public:
    Bubble();
};

#endif // BUBBLE_H
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Comment: Yep - you're right. As you may notice from other replies of mine, I normally do that :) I had an emergency here, and had already entered the code...